# ImageMagick `-duplicate` but to beginning of sequence

Tags: imagemagick

[-duplicate](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#duplicate)

```
convert img*.png -duplicate 3 out.gif
```

makes

```
0 1 2 2 2 2
```

where `0` is `img0.png`, and `1` is `img1.png`, etc, making a GIF. But can I make below?

```
0 0 0 0 1 2 2 2 2
```

that is, append to end *and* start? I get I can use indexing to make

```
0 1 2 2 2 2 0 0 0
```

which is identical in a loop, but I need the `0`s at start in context.

Comment: Please spell out your input image names for clarity.

Comment: `convert img0.png -duplicate 3 img1.png img2.png -duplicate 3 ...` maybe?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Didn't know ops can be chained like that, thanks! Feel free to post as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** for `0 0 0 1 2 3 ... 20 21 21 21` (any number of images) do

```
convert img*.png -write mpr:imgs -delete 0--1 mpr:imgs[0,0,0,1--1,-1,-1] out.gif
```

**Note**: avoid extra commas, e.g. `mpr::imgs[1--1,]` inserts frame `0` (which isn't even selected!) as last frame. Also, `convert` is "legacy' now, `magick` is current, and it's a drop-in replacement for this particular command (and there's a [porting guide](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/porting.php)).

---

Using ImageMagick v6 on Windows command line, this command will let you arrange the order and number of images in any way you need.

```
convert img*.png -write mpr:imgs -delete 0--1 mpr:imgs[0,1,2,2,2,2,0,0,0] out.gif
```

That reads the 3 input images, copies them all into a memory register named "mpr:imgs", deletes the input images from the command, then reads the images from that memory register as you specify in the square brackets. The image index 0 is the first image read into the command, 1 is the second, etc.

Also, using `-duplicate` you can specify which image in the list you want to use according to their order in the list. This command will give the same result as the one above...

```
convert img*.png -duplicate 3 -duplicate 3,0 out.gif
```

The command reads the three images, then `-duplicate 3` makes 3 more of the last image in the list, then `-duplicate 3,0` makes 3 more of the *first* image in the list, index 0.

Another approach would be to use `( -clone ... )` inside parentheses to create the number of duplicates in the order you want.

```
convert img*.png ( -clone 2,2,2 -clone 0,0,0 ) out.gif
```

That reads the 3 input images, clones the third image 3 times, then clones the first image 3 times, giving the same result as the commands above.

These commands are in Windows syntax. For a *nix OS you'd have to escape the parentheses with backslashes "\(...\)".

Also helpful are `-swap`, `-reverse`, `-insert`, and `-delete`  to manipulate the order of images in the list.

Comment: Thanks but doesn't this only show how to _append_ not _prepend_? I'm looking for `0 0 0 0 1 2 2 2 2`

Comment: That's where I would use a method like the first I described. Read the images into a memory register, delete them, then bring them back in any order. This `... mpr:imgs[0,0,0,1,2,2,2] ...` puts the index 0's at the beginning.

Comment: Makes sense, but in practice there's hundreds of images, can we do something like `0, 0, 0,1-199, 200, 200, 200`?

Comment: As far as I know there is no limit to the number of images that can be held in a particular memory register `mpr:anyname` (you can create and use more than one) I'd guess the limit is the amount of memory on your system. You can call them back from that `mpr:imgs[...]` with most any combination of `[1,1,1,3-5,6,6,100-152,0,0,0]` ranges.

Comment: Is `convert img*.png -write mpr:imgs -delete 0--1 mpr:imgs[0,0,0,1--1,-1,-1] out.gif` the right syntax for "repeat first and last three times, all else once"? Worked for me. If so that's nearly perfect and should be edited into the answer, would be nice to specify "0 x3" and "-1 x3" but still acceptable.

Comment: Your `mpr:imgs[0,0,0,1--1,-1,-1]` would fetch the first image 3 times, then the `1--1` would fetch the second through last image, then the `-1` would each fetch the last image in the list. I don't know of a way to call multiples in a row.

Comment: _"fetch the first image 3 times"_ unsure that's right. `mpr:imgs[0,1--1,]` generates two frames of `0`, and `mpr:imgs[0,0,1--1,-1]` three frames of `0` and two of `-1`, and in both instances, all other frames once. `[1--1,]` generates everything once, but puts second frame first and first frame last... Indeed `0,1--1,` also repeated `0` at end. Full example cmd for reference: `convert -delay 200 "C:\im*.png" -write mpr:imgs -delete 0--1 mpr:imgs[0,0,1--1,-1] "C:\test.gif"`

Comment: Ok, it's the comma.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to load your first image, make any duplicates you need, then load the second and make duplicates and load the third and make any duplicates:

```
convert img0.png -duplicate 3 img1.png img2.png -duplicate 3 ...
```

will give your desired image sequence:

```
0 0 0 0 1 2 2 2 2
```